# Rotating CameraImage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, yolo

```
  cameras = await availableCameras();

  cameraController = CameraController(
    cameras[0],
    ResolutionPreset.max,
    imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
  );
  await cameraController.initialize();
  IsCameraInitialized(true);
  update();

  await vision.loadYoloModel(
      labels: 'assets/labels.txt',
      modelPath: 'assets/yolov8n.tflite',
      modelVersion: "yolov8",
      quantization: false,
      numThreads: 1,
      useGpu: false);

  cameraController.startImageStream((CameraImage cameraImage) async {
    try {
      cameraController.lockCaptureOrientation();
      final result = await vision.yoloOnFrame(
          bytesList:
              cameraImage.planes.map((plane) => plane.bytes).toList(),
          imageHeight: cameraImage.height,
          imageWidth: cameraImage.width,
          iouThreshold: 0.4,
          confThreshold: 0.4,
          classThreshold: 0.5);

    } catch (e) {
      print('Error detecting objects: $e');
      

    }
  });
```

I am trying to make this code run also for landscape mode (when you are rotating a phone) but it seems that when I rotate a phone (when the app turns into a landscape mode) it still sends me images in portrait orientation which makes my model fail to recognize objects.

Is it possible to receive images from camera already rotated? Or maybe there is a straightforward way to rotate a CameraImage received from cameraController? (note that it is in yuv420)